# How can I make wget command to read http link with spaces from file?

Tags: wget

The following link image has a space:

```
http://descripciones.intcomex.cl/userfiles/image/210-1140LA XA509LA_190x170.jpg
```

I can get the image using:

```
wget "http://descripciones.intcomex.cl/userfiles/image/210-1140LA XA509LA_190x170.jpg"
```

However, as I have multiple links, I am doing it using a file, like this:

```
wget -i image_links.txt
```

The "wget" commmand won't read the links with spaces from the file. I have try using the following links inside the file (double comma, backslash before the space):

```
"http://descripciones.intcomex.cl/userfiles/image/210-1140LA XA509LA_190x170.jpg"
"http://descripciones.intcomex.cl/userfiles/image/210-1140LA\ XA509LA_190x170.jpg"
```

But none of them work. Does anyone know how I can get it working?

Answer (score 5):

If you put each HTTP URL on a line of its own, it should work:

```
http://server.com/file with space1
http://server.com/file with space2
```

This works for me (GNU wget 1.11.4).

Alternatively, you can URL-escape the spaces, by replacing them with `%20`, as in

```
http://server.com/file%20with%20space1
```

Answer (score 0):

Put each URL on one line and make sure to use UNIX line endings for the .txt file.

I used the following script provided by Python to accomplish this in Windows:

```
python C:\Python27\Tools\scripts\crlf.py textfile.txt
```